# Как реализовать отправку изменения картинки клиентам?

Tags: java, сокет, swing

Пробую реализовать онлайн рисовалку, т.е имеется определённая территория, где любой может нарисовать хоть-что.

Как сделать, чтобы после изменения (один человек нарисовал) и изменения получили все?

Comment: 1 . Формализовать все возможные виды изменений некоторыми командами (например "линия черного цвета толщины 1 из x1,y1 в x2,y2). 2.Рассылать такие изменения всем участникам и применять к канве в их приложениях. 3. Следить за тем, чтобы сообщения были глобально упорядочены (почитать про порядок в распределенных системах: часы Лампорта/векторные часы, например).

Answer (score 2):

В университете была похожая задача. Как один из способов: после того, как человек нажимает на область, и ведет по этой области (рисует линию), обработчик считывает все координаты, рисует маленькие прямые линии между по этим координатам, получается массив координат и нарисованная пользователем линия. Дальше есть несколько вариантов: либо каждый раз, как считывается координата точки, отправлять на сервер, который, в свою очередь, рассылает всем, либо как только пользователь отпустит, отправлять сразу весь массив.